# Does the series Converge or Diverge

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$s_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}k\right)\frac{k}{k+1000}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}, \ \ \ \ \ \ n=1,2,...$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}s_n&=\sum_{k=1}^{[n/2]}(-1)^k\frac{2k}{2k+1000}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2k}}\end{align}$$

Observe how the terms $\frac{2k}{2k+1000}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2k}}$ will eventually decrease to its limit $0$, while $(-1)^k$ alternates signs.

Answer (score 0):

First,
$\cos(\pi k/2)$
is zero for odd $k$;
for even $k$,
if $k=2m$ then
$\cos(\pi k/2)
=\cos(\pi m)
=(-1)^m
$.

Therefore the sum is

$\begin{array}\\
s_n
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}k\right)\frac{k}{k+1000}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\\
&=\sum_{m=1}^{n/2}(-1)^m\frac{m/2}{m/2+1000}\frac{1}{\sqrt{m/2}}\\
&=\sum_{m=1}^{n/2}(-1)^m\frac{m}{m+2000}\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{m}}\\
&=\sqrt{2}\sum_{m=1}^{n/2}(-1)^m\frac{1}{1+2000/m}\frac1{\sqrt{m}}\\
\end{array}
$

If we can show that
$(1+2000/m)\sqrt{m}
$
is increasing,
then this converges by
the alternating series test.

Let $f(x)
=(1+2000/x)\sqrt{x}
= \sqrt{x} + 2000x^{-1/2}
$.
$f'(x)
=(1/2)x^{-1/2}-1000x^{-3/2}
=\frac{x/2-1000}{x^{3/2}}
$.

If $x > 2000$,
$f'(x) > 0$,
so the terms decrease for
$m > 2000$
so the series converges.

Comment: Mind the change of variable (no $m/2$ but $2m$) and the simplification of the $\sqrt{m}$.

Comment: And for the alternating series test you need the series to *decrease* to zero.

Comment: $f(x) \to \infty$ so the terms do converge to zero.